# GlassFish server 4.1 setup

Tags: glassfish

I am trying  setup my application on `Glass fish server 4.1.1`. 
 I have the following error .

The server is up but application doesnt work properly.

> Info:   Timer Service : IntervalTimerDemo_Info
>
> Info:   Current Time : Tue Dec 15 18:09:05 MSK 2015
>
> Info:   Next Timeout : Tue Dec 15 18:09:07 MSK 2015
>
> Info:   Time Remaining : 2000

Comment: This is not an error, just an info line. The error must be somewhere else in the logs. Please go back to the log files and find it.

Comment: Look for the line that starts with ERROR: then post it here

Comment: error:
ERROR:   WELD-000019: Error destroying an instance ru.cntp.eupp.application.admin.UserSession@3c7a14ed of Managed Bean [class ru.cntp.eupp.application.admin.UserSession] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named]
In